# How to configure a non-Safari browser as default on a jailbroken iPhone XR?

Tags: jailbreak, web-browser

How can I set a non-Safari web browser (such as Firefox) as default on a jailbroken iPhone XR, preferably deleting Safari?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BrowserDefault tweak:

- ## [<sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> BrowserDefault](https://repo.packix.com/package/com.lpane.browserdefault)

Unfortunately, there is no way to delete Safari as it is required by the OS.